# WWW::Scripter JE - MouseEvent' is not supported

Tags: perl

I am trying to automate a web application having javascript.

I am using WWW::Scripter for it.

for clicking on a link, I am using following code but it seems that MouseEvent is not supported.

```
$wi->eval ('var theEvent = document.createEvent("MouseEvent");');
$wi->eval ('theEvent.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);');
$wi->eval ('var element = document.getElementsByTagName("li")[3].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];');
$wi->eval ('element.dispatchEvent(theEvent);');
```

Do we have any other way to accomplish it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
use WWW::Scripter;

$wi = new WWW::Scripter;
$wi->use_plugin('JavaScript');

$wi->get('http://...');

$wi->follow_link(url => 
  $wi->eval(
    'document.getElementsByTagName("li")[3].getElementsByTagName("a")[0].href'
  )
);
```

Comment: Thanks. This will be helpful till certain extent.

Comment: You've been posting answers, deleting them, then posting new but similar answers minutes later. You can edit your answers if you don't like them. :) Many of us can still see all of your deleted answers.

Comment: @briandfoy - that's shame - what is deleted should stay deleted - adjust your system (unless you work for government secret services :)